# Why does padding result in a child larger than parent

Tags: html, css

Why does the "Container" overflow its parent, while the "Container2" does not? The only difference is the padding inside the "Container". Why should this stretch its outer size?

```css
.Outside {
  width: 400px;
  height: 1000px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.Container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Container2 {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Item {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Outside">
  <div class="Container">
    <div class="Item">
    </div>
    <div class="Item">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Container2">
    <div class="Item">
    </div>
    <div class="Item">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bvq0mrj4/19/

What is the correct way to avoid this if the padding is required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use **box-siding:border-box** so that the padding won't affect the size of the box

[Box-Sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.Outside {
  width: 400px;
  height: 1000px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.Container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Container2 {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Item {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Outside">
  <div class="Container">
    <div class="Item">
    </div>
    <div class="Item">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Container2">
    <div class="Item">
    </div>
    <div class="Item">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```